# Object type in java

Tags: java

I learnt that Java is not a 100% OOP language and that this is because of data types which are not objects. But according to me, `int` is of type `Integer` and `Integer` belongs to `Number` and `Number` belongs to `Object`. So java is a 100% OOP language. Am I correct?

Comment: This is not twitter.  You can spell out your words.

Comment: If one of the answers is perfect for you, why not accept it? Just click the checkmark on the left.

Answer (score 10):

No, `int` and `Integer` are different. `Integer` is a regular class, which as you know is a subclass of `Number` which itself is a subclass of `Object`. But `int` is a primitive type. It is not a class, so obviously not a subclass of anything; it has no methods or attributes, and generally there is nothing you can do with `int` itself, except declare variables of that type, e.g.

```
int x = 3;
```

Since `int` is not a class, the values of `int` variables are not objects. They have no methods or attributes or properties, and there's not much you can do with them except certain mathematical operations which are handled specially by the compiler.

Note that the Java compiler (recent versions) will automatically insert code to convert an `int` into an `Integer`, or vice-versa, where necessary. So it might *look* like they're the same thing when you write your program, but they are actually not. For instance, if you write

```
Integer y = 5;
```

`javac` translates that into

```
Integer y = Integer.valueOf(5);
```

Or

```
Map<Integer,Integer> m = ...;
m.put(4, 8);
int z = m.get(4);
```

becomes

```
Map<Integer,Integer> m = ...;
m.put(Integer.valueOf(4), Integer.valueOf(8));
int z = m.get(Integer.valueOf(4)).intValue();
```

Comment: To help with further internet searches on the subject, the process of the Java compiler automatically translating between the primitive and object types is called *autoboxing* and *autounboxing* - boxing the primitive within an object, or taking the primitive out of the 'box'.

Comment: Thanks sir.Ur reply was so useful for me

Answer (score 1):

`int` is not an object of the class `Integer`. In Java, not all the data types are objects.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the previous answers (which I think may have missed the point a little) - yes, `int` and `Integer` are two completely different (but related) concepts - one is a primitive, the other an equivalent class. More importantly however, that distinction has **absolutely no bearing whatsoever** on whether Java is an object-oriented language.

Every single Java program uses objects at some point (even if it is just the `String[] args` parameter to your `main` method). As such, Java is unequivocally an object-oriented language, simply because it relies on classes as a primary means of program development. The fact that it supports non-object primative types has nothing to do with that at all.

Comment: I think what the asker meant is that he heard that Java is not 100% OOP, since it has primitives, as opposed to, say Ruby, where everything is an object. He doesn't say that java isn't OOP at all, just that there are some language elements that don't strictly follow the paradigm.